# How to get to the treasure chest at level 1?

Tags: vim-adventures

I must be stupid, I can't get around the rocks to get to the chest in level one. But somehow I managed to get to level 2...

Answer (score 6):

I don't want to give away too much of the answer, so I'll just say that one of the characters in the maze gives a hint;

[image: Vim-Adventure description of Vim "words".]

and the keyboard key you need is available early in Level 3.

After you get it (and a small brown key), return to the treasure chest.
[image]

That should get you on the right path.  I love this game, so please post again if you need more clues.